# Creating property of type structure - error

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties

Why I can't create a property of type structure? I get an error: 'TestTransakcje' cannot expose type 'Transakcje' in namespace 'BazyPolaczenia' through class 'SklepPobieranieDanych'.

```
Public Class SklepPobieranieDanych

    Private Structure Transakcje
        Public kontrahentNazwa As String
        Public listaTowarow() As Towary
    End Structure

    Private Structure Towary
        Public towarSymbol As String
        Public towarNazwa As String
        Public towarIlosc As Integer
        Public towarCena As Double
    End Structure

    Private _testTransakcje As New Transakcje

    Public ReadOnly Property TestTransakcje() As Transakcje  'Here is that error
        Get
            Return _testTransakcje
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm *guessing* it is because `Transakcje` is `Private` - you can't expose a `Private` type from a `Public` member: how would the consumer understand the type? Note also: public mutable fields are a ***very*** bad idea on a value-type.

If I translate that to C#, the compiler error is:

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'SklepPobieranieDanych.Transakcje' is less accessible than property 'SklepPobieranieDanych.TestTransakcje'

which makes the problem pretty clear.